# How to configure a Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and I'm having trouble understanding how to create a simple line chart, with multiple lines. I have done multiple tutorials and everytime I want to customize my code, I look online and find a totally different syntax for creating a chart. What is the best method to configure a chart.

For example below, I created a chart but no I can't figure out how to configure the title. Where is the ChartObject, this syntax makes no sense

```
Private Sub Plot_Click()
    'Declare
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim posX As Integer
    Dim posY As Integer
    Dim sizeX As Integer
    Dim SizeY As Integer

    ' Init
    posX = 100
    posY = 0
    sizeX = 500
    SizeY = 300
    
    ' Set Sheet
    Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    WS.Activate
    
    
    ' Plot Data
    WS.Range("C3:C12").Select
    WS.Range("A3:B12").Select

    WS.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine, posX, posY, sizeX, SizeY).Select
    WS.ChartTitle.Text = "My Chart Title"
End Sub
```

Comment: You should have a `Chart` object, set it `HasTitle` as true, in fact I will post an adaptation of your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try using this adapted code:

```
Private Sub Plot_Click()
    'Declare
    Dim WS As Worksheet, posX As Integer
    Dim posY As Integer, sizeX As Integer, SizeY As Integer

    ' Init
    posX = 100: posY = 0
    sizeX = 500: SizeY = 300
    
    ' Set Sheet
    Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    WS.Activate
    
    ' Plot Data
    'WS.Range("C3:C12").Select 'it it useless if you select another range...
    WS.Range("A3:B12").Select
    
    Dim ch As Chart
    Set ch = WS.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine, posX, posY, sizeX, SizeY).Chart
    With ch
        .HasTitle = True
        .chartTitle.Text = "My Chart Title"
    End With
End Sub
```

But your way of creating a chart looks primitive, no offence...

No need to select anything, this only consumes Excel resources, not bringing any benefit... You may use `SetSourceData` to set the range which now is automatically allocated by preliminarily selecting a range.

Comment: there are some really nice tricks you use, and the code is really clear to understand. Thank you!